# Who or whom, when the person being referred seems to be both a subject and object?

Tags: personal-pronouns, who-whom

**Edit**: I am actually a native speaker of English, and I know that "whom" is not often used these days. However, the reason I am asking this question is to better understand grammar, so that I can compare and contrast English grammar with the grammar of French (a language I am trying to learn).

---

Suppose I want to speak English in a register that still uses the word "whom".

I understand that we use the word "who" if "who" is a subject:

> Who ate my sandwich?

and that we use "whom" if "whom" is an object:

> On whom do you have a crush?

But I'm confused which word I use in the following response about Marc, because the person I'm referring to with "who(m)" seems to be both an object and a subject:

> -- Who are you hoping will choose you as their teammate?
>   -- It is Marc whom I want to ask me to be his teammate.

"I want Marc" makes Marc sound like an object; but "Marc asks me to be his teammate" makes Marc sound like a subject.

Questions:
Do I use "who" or "whom" in the sentence about Marc? Why?

Comment: In the second example, "whom" is not objective (due to the verb *to be*). *who* refers *Mark* (and *It*).

Comment: Could you explain why you think *whom* is an object in the first example? Take a look at "*Which person* are you hoping will choose you as your teammate?" which means the same thing.

Comment: @user3169, for the example, "On whom do you have a crush?", I think "whom" is an object, because I could rearrange that question to be: "You have a crush on whom?". Or, as a statement, I might say "You have a crush on Gilles". In this case, "Gilles" is an object, so "You have a crush on whom?" makes "whom" an object.

Comment: @user3169, (I just read your updated comment, and you have a point). I had written "whom", because if I turned that question into a statement, I might say "You are hoping Marc will choose you as a teammate" ; here, *pause* oh, here, Marc is definitely a subject. Interesting.

Comment: ok, i fixed it. but it is strange. usually, if i say a sentence expressing an emotion about someone, then the question version will be "whom" : "I like Chris" -> "Whom do you like?" . "I hate Chris" -> "Whom do you hate?". "I think Chris is stupid" -> "Whom do you think is stupid?". So that's why I wrote "Whom are you hoping will pick you as their teammate?"

Comment: who vs whom depends on the role of the pronoun in the subordinate clause, not the independent clause

Comment: "Whom do you think is stupid?" is wrong. It's equivalent to asking "Whom is stupid?", which is like saying "Him is stupid."

Answer (score 1):

A quick word about **who** as a question-word. If the question-word replaces a direct object, you should in theory use **whom** but most people would use **who**, expecially in informal speech.

Who does Romeo love? [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/a1-a2-grammar/question-forms)

When the question-word is used in a preposition phrase, more people would be inclined to use **whom**, especially in a formal or written setting, but the majority would use **who** in informal speech.

> To whom do you wish to speak
> Who do you wish to speak to?

Moving on to the use of **who** as a [relative pronoun](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825043658/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/who-or-whom), the situation is similar. If the relative pronoun is substituting for the object of the relative clause, **whom** should be used. One might, for example, use this version in a formal setting:

> The man whom you met yesterday is coming to dinner.

But these versions are much more common in informal speech

> The man who you met yesterday is coming to dinner.
> The man that you met yesterday is coming to dinner.
> The man you met yesterday is coming to dinner.

Looking at your sentence, I think that most native English speakers would simply say

> I want Marc to ask me to be his teammate

If you are desparate to use an over-complicated sentence, you could bypass the **who/whom** issue by saying

> It is Marc **that** I want to ask me to be his teammate.

If you really want to sound pompous, then you could use the formal **whom**.

> It is Marc **whom** I want to ask me to be his teammate.

Comment: I am only interested in the whom-who rules. Can you tell me why it is "whom" in "It is Marc whom I want to ask me to be his teammate"?

Comment: Because the relative pronoun **whom** is substituting for the object X of the clause "I want X"